# Denish (DKK ) Currency Formatting in Java

Tags: java, android, string

In Java/Android , how can I efficiently convert floats like 10.00 to 10,00 as a denish currency.
I am ablle to convert 1000 as required but not for 10 or 10.00

Comment: post some code what you have tried till now

Comment: NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance
                (Locale.getDefault());
        format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("DKK"));

        format.format(amount);

Comment: may i know why down vote ??? ,I have tried in different ways but i am not getting expected output .

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: ok got it i will take care from next time :)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle currency is to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Here is an example from some code that I wrote recently (I just changed the currency to DNK):

```
public static Currency DEFAULT_CURRENCY = Currency.getInstance("DNK");
public static RoundingMode DEFAULT_ROUNDING_MODE = RoundingMode.CEILING;
public static int DEFAULT_SCALE = DEFAULT_CURRENCY.getDefaultFractionDigits();

    /**
     * Convert the value in a BigDecimal having scale and rounding mode aligned to the currency settings
     * @param value
     * @return BigDecimal with the custom scale and settings
     */
    public static BigDecimal setCustomScale(int value) {
        return new BigDecimal(value).setScale(DEFAULT_SCALE, DEFAULT_ROUNDING_MODE);
    }
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/math/BigDecimal.html) is also some example of BigDecimal for Android.